# Generation of abstract class with JCodeModel

Tags: java, code-generation

I'm trying to generate top-level abstract class with [JCodeModel](https://codemodel.java.net/) library, but I can't find any way to change class modifiers. 
It's possible for nested classes (JDefinedClass API provides methods that get modifiers as parameters). But for creation of top level classes I found only JCodeModel API methods that get fully qualified name with or without ClassType (class/interface/annotation/enum) as parameters.

Does anybody can suggest me how to change modifiers of JDefinedClass to make it abstract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create [JPackage](http://fisheye5.cenqua.com/browse/~raw,r=1.1/jaxb-architecture-document/www/doc/com/sun/codemodel/JPackage.html) first and then create class ther.

Something like that.

```
JPackage package = cm._package("test");
JDefinedClass class = package._class(JMod.ABSTRACT,"AbstractTest");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's definitely what I need. Works great. 
Thanks, Alexey!